# See other process previous output with strace

Tags: process, output, strace

Fedora installed
Accessing machine through `PuTTY`.
Somewhere I found that I can see process output by

```
strace -p <pid> -s 9999 -e write
```

But this way I cannot see previous output, only ongoing.
Is there a command to see all previous messages written to that terminal process?

Comment: If the other process is running in (specifically, if it is *writing to*) a terminal (e.g., `xterm`), you may be able to do it by running ``strace`` on the terminal program — but it probably don’t be easy.

Comment: @G-Man, with `strace` I see future output, not past. I guess there is another command to do it. E.g., if I´ve used `screen` to start the process, I could see previous msgs.

Comment: Unless the ouput was written additionally into a (log) file, no. To do so, you need to [redirect the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash). And of course to lookup the information from the past your are interested in within the log, or to monitor the log.